# Callbacks in GWT - save data to the list after click submit button

Tags: java, button, gwt, event-handling

I have a interesting problem with callbacks in GWT. My application have a form, where I have few fields, `OK` button which add something to the list and a main `send button`.

When I fill all fields, click `OK` button first and click `send button`, on the next page, I see the results - everything I wrote to the form is correctly displaying on the confirm site.
But, I have a problem with fields which add something to the list - I have fields, where I put the name and surname, click the button `OK` next to this field which add this data to the list. It works good, I can add as many data I want. This button has his own onClick() method, which do something - this is not important here what. As I said, when I click `OK` button, data is added to the list.
But, I have also my main `send button`. I want to add data to the list with this button, but without clicking on the button `OK`.

Example:
I have put some data to the fields name and surname, I haven't click button `OK` and I click `send` button. The problem is, data was not add to the list and on my confirm page I cannot see the correct result. Of course, under the `send button` I called `click()` method from the `OK` button. 
Maybe I don't know well how callbacks work, but this is very difficult thing for me to solve this problem.

If I manually click on the `OK` button, everything is good. When I do this same thing by programming side, it does not work. I debugged it for a long time, but in any cases everything run identically. Differents are in the final result.

My question is - how to add data to the list only by clicking `send button`?

**EDIT - some pseudo code how it looks right now:**

View class has method (form is a place where I have name and surname fields with button `OK`:

```
public void add(){ 
    form.addButton().click(); 
}
```

Presenter for this view, where I have sendButton:

```
sendButton.addHandler(new ClickHandler(){ 
    @Override 
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) { 
        view.add(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just add click handler to sendButton, so you get all values from every form after clicking? Something like this: form1.getValueAsString(), form2.getValueAsString(), etc. What's the problem?

Comment: Could you paste your code here so I'll try to help you then?

Comment: @Hubert - I have done it. I call method from other form (with this OK button) in send button click handler. It does not work.

Comment: You sould edit your post and paste the code there. What's the problem, again?

Comment: It is highly recomended to use MVP while using GWT. Nice try, but in my opinion you should learn how to use MVP properly. Check out this GWT lesson: http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html - here yoy have nice examples how your problem should be solved. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have learned something before, but I'll try again. Thanks.